# How to catch duplicate entry error using a JDBC sink connector with kafka?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I set up a JDBC sink to use "insert" as the "insert.mode". Naturally this throws up an exception and kills the JDBC sink connector when a duplicate entry is added. Is there a way to have it just log this error and keep on running?

Comment: There's a Connect property called `errors.tolerance`. Have you tried using it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.